# DPMS Suspend on Screen Lock

Tags: xubuntu, display, lock-screen, screensaver

I'm running Xubuntu 20.04 on my laptop (Acer B115-M). I'd like to have the following behavior related to the lock screen, and screensaver:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, aka `xflock4` should lock the screen and turn it off
2. The screensaver should only turn the screen off, and not display a blank screen and then waiting for some timeout to dpms-suspend it.

I tried setting `/general/LockCommand` to `xset dpms force suspend` which kind of works. I suspends the screen, but after a few seconds it comes back on. I was confident this worked, as `xset dpms force suspend` on the command line does exactly what I wanted: It suspends the display, and if you touch a key, it turns on, and then it goes straight to the lock screen.

Could you please help me achieving the behavior I described?

Answer (score 1):

Does it work, if you set `/general/LockCommand` to

```
sh -c 'xfce4-screensaver-command --lock; sleep 0.5; xset dpms force suspend'
```

(I added small delay so that your mouse/keyboard activity does not turn display on immediately.)

Comment: So, there doesn't seem to be a proper setting to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the screen stays on.

Comment: @MaxRied works for me in 19.10, but one monitor (TV) does not support the DPMS setting so I have to use its remote control.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid the built-in laptop screen supports dpms... If I issue the `xset` in terminal then it works. I guess I have to build something on my own...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `/usr/bin/xflock4` (the script behind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> action) does not handle DPMS, as you can see it uses `/general/LockCommand` command if it exists, otherwise it falls back to use 5 different *-screensave-command:

```
# Wait a bit so that user have time to raise finger from a key if
# the script is run in terminal.
[ -t 0 ] && sleep 1

# First test for the command set in the session's xfconf channel
LOCK_CMD=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /general/LockCommand)

if [ -n "$LOCK_CMD" ]; then
    /bin/sh -c "$LOCK_CMD" && exit
    exit_code=$?
    >&2 printf "'%s' exited with status %d\n" "$LOCK_CMD" $exit_code
    exit $exit_code
fi

for lock_cmd in \
    xscreensaver-command \
    light-locker-command \
    xfce4-screensaver-command \
    gnome-screensaver-command \
    mate-screensaver-command
do
    $lock_cmd --lock </dev/null 2>/dev/null && exit
done

# else access locking failed
exit 1
```

Overriding `LockCommand` this field just to make DPMS off will cause no actual lock command to be run, therefore it causes strange issues.

My approach (or workaround) is to create `/usr/sbin/dpms-then-xflock4` with file mode 0755 (i.e. executable):

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/xset dpms force off
exec /usr/bin/xflock4
```

Then set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (or whatever you prefer) to run this command, like this screenshot:

[image: Keyboard - Application Shortcuts]

Once you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, this script will ask DPMS off first, then ask `xflock4` to complete the rest (i.e. the actual "lock").

Have been tested on my desktop, Xubuntu 22.04 (XFCE 4.18).

I have tried other approach like set "Screensaver Preferences - On Screen Keyboard - On screen keyboard command" to `/usr/sbin/dpms-then-xflock4`, but it didn't always work, for example, if you had something playing like YouTube/Twitch in the background (i.e. screensaver was temporily disabled while playing).  It's because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> still call `xflock4` first, and didn't call "On screen keyboard command".